# How to query for records based on a group and ordering?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

Given the following models:

```
User
    id
UserPulses
    id, user_id, group_id, created_at
```

What I would like to do is obtain all of a user's UserPulses grouped by (group_id) and only obtain the most recent UserPulse per group_id. I've been able to do this by looping through group by group, but that takes a large number of queries. Is this possible with one query?

Something like:
    user.user_pulses.group("group_id)")

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this reliably through the usual ActiveRecord interface but you can do it through SQL using a [window function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html). You want some SQL like this:

```
select id, user_id, group_id, created_at
from (
    select id, user_id, group_id, created_at, 
           row_number() over (partition by group_id order by created_at desc, id desc) as r
    from user_pulses
    where user_id = :user_id
) dt
where r = 1
```

and then wrap that in [`find_by_sql`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql):

```
pulses = UserPulses.find_by_sql([%q{
    select id, user_id, group_id, created_at
    from (
        select id, user_id, group_id, created_at, 
               row_number() over (partition by group_id order by created_at desc, id desc) as r
        from user_pulses
        where user_id = :user_id
    ) dt
    where r = 1
}, :user_id => user.id])
```

The window function part essentially does a local GROUP BY with each `group_id`, sorts them (with `id desc` as the secondary sort key as a "just in case" tie breaker), and tacks the per-group row number in `r`. Then the outer query filters out the first in each group (`where r = 1`)`and peels off the original`user_pulses` columns.

Comment: Thank you, try to debug through it. Getting an error "PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 7:             where user_id = :user_id
"

Comment: This appears to return an array which means I can't do pulses.where(:group_id => 1) to get the record from the array w/o requering the db. Is there a way to extract an item from this array?

Comment: @AnApprentice: `find_by_sql` wants you to wrap the args in an Array when you use placeholders. I just added the missing `[` and `]`. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AnApprentice: You'd have to add that sort of thing to the SQL manually, ActiveRecord doesn't really understand anything more complicated than `select * from t where a = b`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PostgreSQL specific extension of the SQL feature `DISTINCT`: [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (group_id)
       id, user_id, group_id, created_at
FROM   user_pulses
WHERE  user_id = :user_id
ORDER  BY group_id, created_at DESC, id; -- id just to break ties
```

Simpler than window functions (but not as portable) and probably fastest.
More [details under this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3800551/939860).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, perhaps. But there could be multiple records for a user/group_id combo if they share the same date.

```
SELECT p.id, p.user_id, p.group_id, p.created_at
  FROM UserPulses p
      ,( SELECT user_id, group_id, MAX(created_at) as max_date
           FROM UserPulses
           GROUP BY user_id, group_id ) m
  WHERE u.user_id = m.user_id
    AND u.group_id = m.group_id
    AND u.created_at = m.max_date
```

Comment: There will in mos cases multiple records per user/group_id per day. Suggestions?